# Using cronjob and email to create a texting "server"

Tags: linux, scripting, cron

So the idea of this was to create a "server" that would work by reading my email and looking for certain key headers in the email. When an email with a certain header is detected, the commands in it are interpreted and run. These are not Linux commands mind you, just different commands I have made available. Let me give you an example:

- I send from my phone the text "Computer, define Hello" to my email.
- My email receives the text, and saves it as "Computer, define Hello".
- My computer downloads my newest email and sees "Computer, define
  Hello", and runs the command "define Hello".
- It sends the results of
  sending the command back to me, which would be the definition of the
  word "Hello".

The code actually works fine on its own, and almost works fine on cronjob. In fact, the only command that's having a problem is the command "sendmail" which is what sends the mail back to my phone.

I saw that people have talked about using "MAILTO" to send email. I'm not using MAILTO but am instead using a combination of gmail, mailx, and msmpta to get the job done. sendmail works normally, just not through cronjob for some reason. Here is the page where I got instructions on how to do this:
http://tuxtweaks.com/2012/10/send-gmail-from-the-linux-command-line/

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the command you use to send mail? MAILTO in crontab is more for telling crontab where it should send error/output logs.

Comment: Have a look at sending mail to your gmail account via SSMTP; see [http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-with-gmail-and-ssmtp/](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-with-gmail-and-ssmtp/) for a HOWTO. I've ran into trouble recently setting up gmail accounts with sendmail, but with SSMTP it was quite painless.

Comment: I've fixed the problem by just not using cronjob and instead making an infinite while loop with a sleep 60 at the end :) thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by avoiding cronjob altogether, using an infinite while loop, and using sleep(2000) (or some other large number) to delay when the script runs.